# Trouble displaying £ sign in confirm box - Javascript solution needed

Tags: javascript, special-characters

Does anyone know how to display a £ sign in a confirm box in Javascript?

An example would be:

```js
confirm("Please confirm price of £2.99")
```

This works fine on this code snippet but not when I try it in my webpage, When I try this the "£" sign is rendered as a ? in a black triangle?

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to change your default font?

Answer (score 2):

Your question states that the "£" sign is rendered incorrectly (a ? in a black trinagle).
This means the browser thinks it should render it in a way that you didn't expect.

The "£" sign is Unicode `U+00A3`, but can be represented in many ways depending on *encoding*.

You need to tell your browser which unicode to use. This is done in HTML, not JavaScript. In the `<head>` tag, add:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#charset

Once you have set which encoding to use, you have various options for how write the "£" symbol:

- You can simply write `£`
- You can use HTML entity:

  - `&pound;`
  - `&#xA3;`
  - `&#163;`

Full code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>confirm("Please confirm price of £2.99");</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, I have <meta charset="utf-8" /> in the HTML, but the page still renders the £ sign as a ? in a black triangle.

Comment: @Shizaro in which browser on which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution to this by using String.fromCharCode but its not very elegant. I assume that I need to set some kind of meta charset header in my HTML but not sure which!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).